# Convert hash values from decimal to percentage in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I am creating a table within a PDF using the following hash:

```
percentages = {
"group one" => 0.2,
"group two" => 0.6666666666666666,
"group three" => 0.2,
"group four" => 0.03333333333333333,
"group five" => 0.03333333333333333,
"group six" => 0.06666666666666667
}
```

I am calling `.transpose` on the hash keys and values:

`[percentages.keys, percentages.values].transpose`

This works as expected, but I now need to convert the decimals to percentages. Instead of `.2`, I need to show 20%. Instead of `0.06666666666666667`, I need to show 7%.

Is there a clean way to do this without altering the original hash/creating a new one?

Comment: `.2` is not a valid Ruby expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
[percentages.keys, percentages.values.map {|x| (x * 100).round.to_s + '%'}].transpose
```

It simply takes each value and multiplies by 100 (converts to percentage), calls `round` (to remove the decimal, i.e. `6.666667 -> 7`), and then calls `to_s` to convert it to a string and concatenate to `'%'`.

Comment: That does it - I was trying to call `.round` on `percentage.values`, not thinking about the `.map` method. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Not so fast, @AGS, lest we discourage other answers.

Comment: Sure, Cary, a variety of answers are great.  But a new user who states in a comment that the solution works might not know that a "better" way of thanking the person who proposed the solution is to "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
percentages.map{|k, v| [k, "#{(v * 100).round}%"]}
```

Comment: What could be simpler?

Answer (score 2):

Another way, using zip rather than transpose:

```
percentages.keys.zip percentages.values.map {|v| "#{(100*v).round.to_s}%"}
  #  => [["group one", "20%"], ["group two", "67%"], ["group three", "20%"],
  #      ["group four", "3%"], ["group five", "3%"], ["group six", "7%"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to convert and round uses [`String.%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25) which is akin to [`format`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format), [`printf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) or [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) in the Kernel:

```
[
  0.2,
  0.6666666666666666,
  0.2,
  0.03333333333333333,
  0.06666666666666667
].each do |f|
  puts "%.0f%%" % (f * 100)
end
# >> 20%
# >> 67%
# >> 20%
# >> 3%
# >> 7%
```

From that point it's easy to build the rest of what you're looking for.